# Flutter requires Xcode 14 or higher

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart

`I recently updated my Flutter version and then I ran the Flutter Doctor command, and in my terminal it says everything is fine, but you need to update xcode, while the AppStore has not given any update for xcode.

> ```
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.1, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
> [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4)
>     ✗ Flutter requires Xcode 14 or higher.
>       Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
> [✓] Network resources
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
> ```

> Doctor found issues in 1 category.
> `

Comment: Which version of Xcode you've been using?

Comment: You likely need to update MacOS first, then you'll get the Xcode version available in the store.

Comment: Please share your current Xcode version

Comment: As I mentioned Xcode 13.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems **Xcode 14** is compulsory required with flutter version **3.13.x**
Same issue I'm facing with **Big Sur** MacOS.

You need to download latest Xcode (min 14 is required) so, min MacOS - **Monterey** is required to use XCode 14+.

Still, you can use lower version of XCode but it seems you can not use `flutter run` command to test your development

For more info, see [release notes - 3.13.0](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.13.0)